# Вставить значение в xml-содержимое

Tags: java, xml, строки, spring

В спринг-бут проекте в папке resources есть шаблон xml. Меняется в нем только одно значение. Каким способом можно получать содержание файла как строку со внедренным значением $value в коде.

```
<body>
   <phone>$value</phone>
</body>
```

Сейчас просто захардкодил часть xml до значения и после и конкатенировал строку.

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения файла из ресурсов можно написать следующий метод:

```
private String readResource(String name) {
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try (
        InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(name);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
    ) {
        return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

И после чтения заменить `$value` через `replace`:

```
readResource("file.xml").replace("$value", "{some_value}");
```